# Qt 5.0.1 Can't launch program

Tags: qt, compiler-errors

I've strange problem with Qt. Recently I downloaded Qt 5.0.1. And now every project I start in Qt as "Build->Start" works well. But if I start Release version of it from explorer there's no effect. And if I start Debug version from explorer I have this error

[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: Are the necessary DLL's in the directory where the exe can find them?

Comment: I would say this is a path problem. Make sure the correct Qt dlls are in the path.

Comment: Yes. All dlls in one directory with app.

Comment: You might nevertheless want to check with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) or [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) whether you are really using the right DLLs

Comment: Yes. You are right. Some dlls are needed. I added wer.dll, bcrypt.dll, ncrypt.dll, IEshims.dll. Now it askes me API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-BASE-L1-1-0.dll and API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTHREADS-L1-1-0.dll. Is it normal?

Comment: As I can see these DLLs are from win 7. So Qt 5.0.1  doesn't work with win xp? If so it's true cross-platform.

Comment: Can't you compile Qt under XP? I would try myself however I have not used an XP machine in a few years.

Comment: On PC I have win 7, and on laptop I've win XP as it's quite old. I tried to start program on Win 7, but Dependency Worker shows that GPSVC.dll and SYSNTFY.dll are for 64x platform. And now I can't find these DLLS for x86.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to copy plugins directory beside your application.
Dependency Walker wont show them in the list, because they're loaded in runtime by Qt Core libs. So final executable have no idea about linkage or location of those plugins at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

It precisely says, what it needs - the "windows" plugin. It should be located in folder "platforms", as `qwindows.dll`.

You can read more in [Qt5 official windows deployment guide](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/deployment-windows.html), but rather look on the forums for more practical info, i. e. [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/25714).

In short: to make your application (compiled with Qt built dynamically) run on other machine, you must include many libs with it. All of them should be copied  from

```
Qt_installation_folder/Qt_version/used_compiler/bin
&
Qt_installation_folder/Qt_version/used_compiler/plugins/
```

QML plugins should be copied from

```
Qt_installation_folder/Qt_version/used_compiler/qml
&
Qt_installation_folder/Qt_version/used_compiler/imports
```

It is very important to copy Qt libraries from exact the same compiler as used in the project.

Below I present you an example (borrowed from [above second link](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/25714)) with explanations:

```
ROOT FOLDER
│   YourApp.exe
│   D3DCompiler_43.dll        // } \
│   libEGL.dll                // }  --> If you use Qt built with ANGLE support
│   libGLESv2.dll             // } /
│   
│   icudt49.dll               // } \
│   icuin49.dll               // }  --> If you use Qt built with WebKit (Unicode support)
│   icuuc49.dll               // } /
│   
│   Qt5Core.dll               // --> Basic Qt module, always needed
│   Qt5Gui.dll                // --> If you use GUI module
│   
│   Qt5Network.dll            // } \
│   Qt5Qml.dll                // }  --> If you use QML
│   Qt5Quick.dll              // }  --> module
│   Qt5V8.dll                 // } /
│   
│   Qt5Multimedia.dll         // } --> If you use multimedia
│   Qt5MultimediaQuick_p.dll  // } --> from QtQuick
│
├───platforms
│       qwindows.dll          // Always needed for windows
│
├───QtMultimedia              // If you import QtMultimedia 5.x 
│       declarative_multimedia.dll
│       plugins.qmltypes
│       qmldir
│       Video.qml
│
├───QtQuick.2                 // If you import Qt.Quick 2.x
│       plugins.qmltypes
│       qmldir
│       qtquick2plugin.dll
```